# Animação com RequestAnimationFrame - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Com base no site do OneDrive, onde se tem um menu drop-down do lado esquerdo que quando clicado na div **OneDrive** ele carrega o menu para baixo; e se clicado novamente ele voltado no primeiro estado, que é o menu recolhido.

[image: Imagem do OneDrive]

Estou tentando fazer esta animação, só que usando apenas Javascript. Depois de muita pesquisa, vi que não é recomendável usar algum temporizador para fazer estes tipos de animações. O **RequestAnimationFrame** é usado para isso.
Segue o [código](http://jsfiddle.net/WesleyRedfield/zjfmg4n6/3/) onde já consegui fazer boa parte do que desejo.
Acho que o que está acontecendo é que não consigo parar a animação no devido momento, e, por consequência, não consigo manipular corretamente o cancelRequestAnimationFrame.

No código, o que estou tentando fazer é que quando eu clicar no quadrado ele vá para baixo. Quando clicar novamente ele vá para cima. E fique fazendo apenas estes dois movimentos, para que depois eu consiga fazer um menu com base nisto.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você complicou demais: http://jsfiddle.net/smpfjwg8/. E dá pra fazer isso com CSS também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade em usar tanto o javascript quando é possível usar estilos para estas tarefas.

```js
var acao = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.nextElementSibling.style.height)
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.height = '0px';
  else
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.height = '';
};
var sub = document.querySelectorAll('[role=sub]');
sub[0].addEventListener('click', acao);
sub[1].addEventListener('click', acao);
```

```css
main {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
[role=sub] {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
[role=sub]:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
div {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
[role=item] {
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div role="sub">OneDrive</div>
  <div role="item">
    <div>DADOS #01</div>
    <div>DADOS #02</div>
    <div>DADOS #03</div>
    <div>DADOS #04</div>
    <div>DADOS #05</div>
  </div>
  <div role="sub">Grupos</div>
  <div role="item">
    <div>GRUPO #01</div>
    <div>GRUPO #02</div>
    <div>GRUPO #03</div>
    <div>GRUPO #04</div>
    <div>GRUPO #05</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Achei sua solução **muito** interessante mesmo. Me ajudou perfeitamente (diminui meu JS). Agora, por favor, me tire algumas dúvidas que ficaram: 

1 - No Javascript, qual a lógica nas linhas 2, 3, 4 e 5? (Quando height for 0 ele faz alguma coisa? Caso contrário ... Enfim, fiquei com dúvida);

2 - Ao adicionar o addEventListener(acao) nas duas divs pensei que clicando numa div, automaticamente a outra também receberia o mesmo efeito que a de cima. Ou seja, os efeitos aconteceriam simultaneamente. Só que eu posso clicar no de cima e apenas o de cima move; o mesmo com o a de baixo. Obg

Comment: @WesleyRedfield a ideia destas linhas iniciais é fazer com que a propriedade do css `transition: 0.5s;` trabalhe, digo, as divs já possuem tamanhos definidos assim alterando esse valor para zero, no caso do  exemplo, faz com que aconteça a animação. Já a duvida referente  ao `addEventListener`, não executa todos ao mesmo momento por conta que na função depende somente da origem, não tem um vinculo especifico, essa parte `e.target` é o componente em si que recebeu a ação, só para ele que vai atuar.